# Known cases of block-withholding attacks

Tags: mining-pools, attack, selfish-mining, block-withholding

At the moment I am doing a course about Bitcoin. The topic of the last session was the block-withholding attack and the course (being from 2014) claimed that there are no known attacks so far.

Is block-withholding a strategy used by mining pools in 2021? If so, where can I find evidence to back that up?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article from 2016 it seems Slush pool had noticed or someone reported issues related to block withholding:
http://organofcorti.blogspot.com/2016/02/detecting-unintentional-block.html

Not sure if it works in 2021 and which mining pools are affected.

While researching about OP_CTV I read about *trustless coordination free mining pools*: https://utxos.org/uses/miningpools/ so we can assume OP_CTV fixes this however it's not activated yet.

> This type of mining pool has no trusted operator and requires no coordination. This eliminates various types of mining pool attacks, such as block witholding.

Comment: Note that "block witholding" can refer to two completely different attacks: (1) a means for large mining *pools* to get a better than proportional share of the income or (2) a way for mining pool *users* to hurt the pool's income by reducing their income while still being paid out. I suspect OP is asking about (1). Your article linked to is about (2). I'm not sure about the CTV one.

Comment: Yeah, the former was originally referred to as selfish-mining, the latter as "block solution withholding" or just "block withholding". Since then, a bunch of academic papers have used "block withholding" to refer to selfish mining, though, so I guess that distinction is no longer tangible.

Comment: Thanks @PieterWuille learnt something new. Will wait for OP to respond and reading more about "block withholding".

Answer (score -3):

I found a lot of papers about block with holding attacks

This seems a survey
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309628092_Bitcoin_Block_Withholding_Attack_Analysis_and_Mitigation

These r newer
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343236094_Countering_Block_Withholding_Attack_Efficiently

https://www.aimspress.com/article/id/4266

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0951832018310494

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9284756

Reading the abstracts  this includes some of the *Selfish Mining* ways (I'm sure I read the idea in the IEEE paper in a Selfish Mining paper:
*Detective Mining: Selfish Mining Becomes
Unrealistic under Mining Pool Environment*,
Suhyeon Lee and Seungjoo Kim,
CIST(Center for Information Security Technologies), Korea University, Korea; ADD(Agency for Defense Development), Korea.)
I don't think *Selfish Mining* or *Block With Holding* is something u'll read in the news about, it is a miner or a pool used a block mining efforts; only maybe if it helped in a 51% attack which the papers point as a risk.

Wait, I did find more in my library under Selfish Mining
https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/selfish-mining-explained
https://outlast.me/selfish-mining-in-five-tweets/
In this one there's a curve unfortunately I don't know its source about ratio of Selfish Mining in known pools
[image]

[I added this part for the sake of promoting knowledge, understanding, scientific research,... nothing more]

I also wondered would it be a malicious way to do front running?ie convince a high bidder ( would be paid more to get his TX as fast as possible) that his/her TX is guaranteed say 1st place in ur block, while u plan to drop the whole block & front run with another TX (maybe I did read that in a paper before, *MEV* ?)
& yes I did read about it under MEV, they're called *Privately Mined Transactions* or *Private Transactions* , they didn't allow more links so I'll just add the screenshots I made about it ( u can search for urself under these terms)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The question asked for evidence that block-withholding (probably selfish mining) attacks have happened in practice. This answer lists a number of theoretical papers without addressing the question.